# How do EVs apply different levels of braking resistance to slow a car, without using brake pads?

Tags: motor, automotive

How this variable resistance applied in circuitry?

Comment: Same way acceleration is applied: torque is proportional to motor current.

Comment: Motor is also a generator. It all boils down to at what rate you want to take energy from the generaror back to batteries.

Comment: This is a lot more complicated than implied by the length of the question. And there is an added complexity because in practical systems the braking isn't all regenerative and is combined with mechanical braking.

Comment: There is also the control issue because you want to maintain antilock braking performance.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not resistance in the electrical sense, otherwise the energy would be wasted.  In simple terms the motor, now acting as a generator, is rapidly switched on and off; if it is off most of the time then there will be little retardation, while if it’s on all the time there will be maximum braking.  The energy is fed back into the vehicle’s battery.  The switching is typically done in the kilohertz range; sometimes you can hear a whine caused by this.